# TFPT not working with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-power-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Team Foundation Power Tools 2015 and the explorer extension and the command line tool is not working. When i type tfpt in Devleoper Command Prompt for VS2015, i get the following error.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=12.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   at
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CommandLine.CommandLine.Main(String[] args)
```

I have run things in admin and that makes no difference. 
Here is what I get when i run the TF command.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>tf
Microsoft (R) TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool, Version 14.0.24712.0
```

TFS is working fine in VS. When I had VS2013 and TFS Power Tools 2013 everything was working fine. What else do I need to do to get this working?

edit: I have resolved the command line issue, but now the shell extension isnt working. I do not see the green check boxes in windows explorer, and when i right click a folder I do not get a TFS option. I am noticing multiple processes for it which is obviously does not seem good. Continues to create new processes until memory problems arise.

[image]

Additionally, Seeing these 2 events in the windows log.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        TFSShellExt
Date:          9/25/2016 7:25:40 PM
Event ID:      3
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MyComp
Description:
TFS Shell Extension event:\n Failed to start COMProvider while updating workspaces.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="TFSShellExt" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32770">3</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-09-25T23:25:40.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>156525</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>MyComp</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Failed to start COMProvider while updating workspaces.</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

and

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        TFSShellExt
Date:          9/25/2016 7:25:40 PM
Event ID:      3
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MyComp
Description:
TFS Shell Extension event:\n More than 5 failed calls to com provider. 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="TFSShellExt" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32770">3</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-09-25T23:25:40.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>156524</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>MyComp</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>More than 5 failed calls to com provider. </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Do you have any 2013 version installed on your machine? It's trying to find the reference with version 12.

Comment: I did have VS2013. TFPT worked, deleted VS2013, TFPT is then broken. Upgraded TFPT, still not working. Where can i clean up the reference for VS looking for VS2013 dll's?

Comment: Did you uninstall the Power Tools 2013 after delete VS2013?

Comment: Yes. See my update please.

Comment: Can you uninstall both 2013 and 2015 version for Power Tools first to check if these process disappears from Task Manager?

Comment: Uninstalled, they are now gone. Exe is gone uninstall was clean.

Comment: Then if you reinstall the 2015 version, does it works? And can you also try reinstall the NET Framework on your machine since the shell extension requires .NET 4.0.

Comment: nope, reinstalled and still the same problems. I have .net 4.5 and 4.6 installed, will try a fresh .net install if i can. do the 2 event logs provide any insight?

Comment: It indicates that the extension cannot instantiate to the COM. Do you have any message like "TFS Shell Extension event:\n Successfully registered notification event with COM provider" in event log?

Comment: I had a few of those 9/23. But have not seen one today or yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with my VS2015.3 and [PowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) on my machine, but couldn't reproduce your issue:

[image]

The error complains `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=12.0.0.0'`, you may try to clean the cache in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache` to see whether it helps you.

Comment: I have a folder for TF 4.0, 5.0, and 6.0. Are you aware which is the correct one i should be seeing?

Comment: You can clean all of them.